# Tex4ht: Lists inside multicols

Tags: multicol, enumitem, tex4ht

I use the multicol package to generate "2x2" lists (two rows, two columns), which works fine with pdflatex but not with tex4ht.  While multicol works with tex4ht generally, there seems to be something about including a list environment that causes strange line-break behaviour (in tex4ht).

I also use special labels for the lists, which I've included because it's important that any solution, if any, work with the these special labels (I really only need "2x2" lists for problems that use these labels).  However the issue is not caused by these special labels, as the mwe shows.

Here's the pdf output:

[image: pdf file]

And the html output:

[image: html output]

While the right formatting can be achieved using a tabular environment, I'd really much rather be able to use lists.

Here's the mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %necessary for MathJax?
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} % for customized lists; note INLINE option
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\ifdefined\HCode

\definecolor{mcyellow}{rgb}{247,244,58}
\definecolor{mcblue}{rgb}{123,104,238}
\definecolor{mcpink}{rgb}{247,58,241}
\definecolor{mcgreen}{rgb}{118,247,58}
\definecolor{mcorange}{rgb}{247,165,58}

\newcommand{\mcY}{\hspace{0pt}\colorbox{mcyellow}{\sffamily Y}}
\newcommand{\mcB}{\hspace{0pt}\colorbox{mcblue}{\sffamily \textcolor{White}{B}}}
\newcommand{\mcP}{\hspace{0pt}\colorbox{mcpink}{\sffamily \textcolor{White}{P}}}
\newcommand{\mcG}{\hspace{0pt}\colorbox{mcgreen}{\sffamily G}}
\newcommand{\mcO}{\hspace{0pt}\colorbox{mcorange}{O}}

\else

\newcommand{\mcY}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\colorbox[RGB]{247,244,58}{\sffamily\textbf{Y}}\quad\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}
\newcommand{\mcB}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\colorbox[RGB]{123,104,238}{\sffamily\textcolor{white}{\textbf{B}}}\quad\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}
\newcommand{\mcP}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\colorbox[RGB]{247,58,241}{\sffamily\textcolor{white}{\textbf{P}}}\quad\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}
\newcommand{\mcG}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\colorbox[RGB]{118,247,58}{\sffamily\textbf{G}}\quad\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}
\newcommand{\mcO}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\colorbox[RGB]{247,165,58}{\sffamily\textcolor{white}{\textbf{O}}}\quad\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}

\fi

\begin{document}

This list looks good in pdf and html:
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
  \end{enumerate}

  I need two-column lists, such as this, which looks perfect in pdf but poor in html:
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[\mcY] Item
    \item[\mcB] Item
    \item[\mcP] Item
    \item[\mcG] Item
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

  The issue is not caused by my special labels, as the next list shows:
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item
    \item Item
    \item Item
    \item Item
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

And here's the config:

```
\Preamble{html}

\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link href="\FileName.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\Hnewline}} 

\Configure{fbox}
{\HCode{<span class="fbox">}\bgroup \fboxrule=0pt}
{\egroup\HCode{</span>}}
\Css{span.fbox {border: 1pt solid black;}}

\Css{.colorbox {
  margin-left: 0em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
  padding:0.2em;
} 
}

\Configure{HColor}{mcyellow}{rgb(247,244,58)}
\Configure{HColor}{mcblue}{rgb(123,104,238)}
\Configure{HColor}{mcpink}{rgb(247,58,241)}
\Configure{HColor}{mcgreen}{rgb(118,247,58)}
\Configure{HColor}{mcorange}{rgb(247,165,58)}

\begin{document}


\EndPreamble
```

Comment: I don't know TeW4ht, but you might take a look at either `shortlst` or `tasks` for  lists aligned in columns.